# Writing a function that compares lowercase version of two strings, and can handle 'None' inputs

Tags: python

I would like to write a function that returns true if the lowercase version of two strings is the same and false otherwise. I.e.:

```
def strcmp_lowercase(s1, s2)
    return s1.lower() == s2.lower()
```

However, I would like this function to be able to deal with receiving inputs that are NoneType instead of strings, and to return true if both inputs are None. With the above function, this results in an error as a NoneType object has no .lower() method,

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Here is one possible solution,

```
def strcmp_lowercase(s1, s2)
    s1_lower = s1.lower() if s1 else None
    s2_lower = s2.lower() if s2 else None

    return s1_lower == s2_lower
```

This doesn't seem like a great way to do it though, is there a more elegant way? Thanks!

Comment: `s1, s2 = s1 or "", s2 or ""` maybe? This converts your inputs to strings and then the rest of the function will work fine. Downside is that `""` matches `None`.

Comment: how are you calling `strcmp_lowercase`  Why would you try comparing `None` or do you mean `How do i handle, if not a string is given? ` -> Use `Exceptions`

Comment: @user1767754 yes I am intending for this function to be used to compare class variables, which can be strings but can also be None

Comment: Why is lowercase so important?

Comment: I need the comparison to be case-insensitive

Comment: You may be interested in [PEP-505](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0505), which proposes syntax that would let you write `return s1?.lower() ?? False == s2?.lower() ?? False`. (`s1?.lower() == s2?.lower()` would not suffice, since a `str` and a `None` cannot be compared in Python 3).

Answer (score 1):

You can check the types of the inputs using `isinstance`.

```
def strcmp_lowercase(s1, s2):
    if isinstance(s1, str) and isinstance(s2, str):
        return s1.lower()==s2.lower()
    elif s1 is None and s2 is None:
        return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

This is slightly more idiomatic:

```
def strcmp_lowercase(s1, s2):
    if s1: s1 = s1.lower()  
    if s2: s2 = s2.lower()
    return s1 == s2
```

Comment: Collapsing the `if` statement on to one line is hardly idiomatic in Python.

Comment: I only said it was slightly more idiomatic and concise than the possible function given in the question. Although I feel that collapsing the `if` statement to one line is acceptable and clearly readable.